# Table in the middle

Tags: html, css

I need to have table in the middle of the page, but content of my table is on the right side like on the picture.

[EDIT]: Sorry I forget to say that just the responsive tabke is messed up you can look at it on edastehlik.wz.cz viewport: 500 - 1050

[image: Not like this]

But I would need to have it like this:

[image: Like this]

```css
.tabulkaodesilac {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 400px;
  display: block;
}

#jmeno,
#e-mail,
#spam,
#predmet {
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: rgba(141, 109, 182, 0.75);
  width: 350px;
  height: 25px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-style: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
  .tabulkaodesilac {
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #jmeno,
  #e-mail,
  #spam,
  #predmet {
    width: 70%;
    font-family: verdana;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="tabulkaodesilac">
  <tr>
    <td><input id="jmeno" type="text" name="jmeno" placeholder="Vaše Jméno" /> <br></td>
    <td><input id="e-mail" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Váš E-mail" /><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="spam" type="text" name="spam" placeholder="Zadejte aktuální rok" /><br></td>
    <td><input id="predmet" type="text" name="predmet" placeholder="Předmět" /> <br></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table has `margin-left: 400px;` AND `display: block;` - especially the `display: block;` actually prevents it from being a table (a table has to have `display: table`)  - so just erase this (and also that too large margin) and it will work:

```css
.tabulkaodesilac {
  width: 100%;
}

#jmeno,
#e-mail,
#spam,
#predmet {
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: rgba(141, 109, 182, 0.75);
  width: 350px;
  height: 25px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-style: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
  .tabulkaodesilac {
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #jmeno,
  #e-mail,
  #spam,
  #predmet {
    width: 70%;
    font-family: verdana;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="tabulkaodesilac">
  <tr>
    <td><input id="jmeno" type="text" name="jmeno" placeholder="Vaše Jméno" /> <br></td>
    <td><input id="e-mail" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Váš E-mail" /><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="spam" type="text" name="spam" placeholder="Zadejte aktuální rok" /><br></td>
    <td><input id="predmet" type="text" name="predmet" placeholder="Předmět" /> <br></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry I forget to say that just the responsive tabke is messed up you can look at it on edastehlik.wz.cz viewport: 500 - 1050

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `margin: 0 auto` for your table and remove other stuff from there:

```css
.tabulkaodesilac {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#jmeno,
#e-mail,
#spam,
#predmet {
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: rgba(141, 109, 182, 0.75);
  width: 350px;
  height: 25px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-style: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
  .tabulkaodesilac {
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #jmeno,
  #e-mail,
  #spam,
  #predmet {
    width: 70%;
    font-family: verdana;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="tabulkaodesilac">
  <tr>
    <td><input id="jmeno" type="text" name="jmeno" placeholder="Vaše Jméno" /> <br></td>
    <td><input id="e-mail" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Váš E-mail" /><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="spam" type="text" name="spam" placeholder="Zadejte aktuální rok" /><br></td>
    <td><input id="predmet" type="text" name="predmet" placeholder="Předmět" /> <br></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry I forget to say that just the responsive tabke is messed up you can look at it on edastehlik.wz.cz viewport: 500 - 1050